# laravel sum of Records.records.record.column in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Here is the relation

1. transaction `hasMany` Carts
2. Cart `belongsTo` product
3. product`->`price

here is the Model class

```
//# TransactionModel
public function getCarts(){
    return $this->hasMany(CartModel::class, 'transaction_id','id');
}
//# CartModel
public function getProduct(){
    return $this->belongsTo(ProductModel::class,'product_id','id');
}
```

what i want to achieve is to get total price of current transaction**s**(many)

what i do now is still iterate per transation and sum the price in `$total`

```
 Class TransactionModel{
 public static function getTotalPrice($transactions){
    $total = 0;
    foreach($transactions as $transaction){
            $total += $transaction->getCarts->sum('getProduct.price');
    }
    return $total;
 }
```

how to this in eloquent code
thanks

Comment: It should be something like `$transaction->getCarts->product->sum('price')`

Comment: @Iftikharuddin thats what i did, only get `current transation`. what we want to achieve is total price of `many transaction(S)`

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Also, please may you show the code for all 3 models.

Comment: Can you update your question with Model relationships? what dos getcarts do?

Comment: @RossWilson updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found a better way  with collection reduce instead of foreach

```
 $totalPrice = $transactions->reduce(function($carry, $current){
                    return $carry + $current->getCarts->sum('getProduct.price');
               },0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think this should work :

```
Class TransactionModel{

    public function getTotalPrice(){

        return $this->getCarts()->withCount([
            'getProduct' => function($q){ 
                return $q->select(DB::raw("SUM(price) as price_sum")); 
            }
        ])->get()->sum('getProduct_count');
    }

}
```

Comment: $this in static function ?

Comment: Ahh Thanks @faizan.sh I forgot to remove static word, Thanks :) Updated my answer

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what we want to achieve is total price of many `transaction(S)` see my question first word is `Records`. $this means `1 record`